# PHP / MySQL - Confusing Query

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to construct a query that goes over 3 tables and im COMPLETELY stumped ... my knowledge limit is basic 1 table query and i need some help before i stick my head in a blender.

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM internalrole WHERE introle = $imarole
```

Im fine with that part .. its the next thats getting me all stressed.

That query returns the following columns ( id, user_id, introle, proven, used )

What i then need to do is take the user_id from the results returned and use it to get the following

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = user_id(from previous query) AND archive = 0 and status = 8
```

I need to put that into 1 query, but wait, theres more .... from the results there, i need to check if that user's 'id' is in the availability table, if it is, check the date ( column name is date ) and if it matches todays date, dont return that one user.

I need to put all that in one query :S ... i have NO IDEA how to do it, thinking about it makes my head shake ... If someone could help me out, i would be eternaly grateful.

Cheers,

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*
    FROM internalrole ir 
        INNER JOIN users u
            ON ir.user_id = u.id
                AND u.archive = 0
                AND u.status = 8
        LEFT JOIN availability a
            ON ir.user_id = a.user_id
                AND a.date = CURDATE()
    WHERE ir.introle = $imarole
        AND a.user_id IS NULL /* User does NOT exist in availability table w/ today's date */
```

**EDIT**: This second query is based on the comments below, asking to show only users who *do* exist in the availability table.

```
SELECT u.*
    FROM internalrole ir 
        INNER JOIN users u
            ON ir.user_id = u.id
                AND u.archive = 0
                AND u.status = 8
        INNER JOIN availability a
            ON ir.user_id = a.user_id
    WHERE ir.introle = $imarole
```

Comment: wow ... thats a head hurter ... thanks for that ... would that return all the 'users' that arent in the availability table though?

Comment: @Cecil: Yes it would. Is that the desired result or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: That is the exact desired result ... just running it now :) .. fingers crossed

Comment: Is there any way to reverse this so that it shows if the user DOES exist in the availability table?

Comment: @Cecil: 1. Change the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN, 2. Remove the date test from the JOIN conditions and 3. Remove the user_id IS NULL from the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli - Thank you for that ... For some reason it doesnt seem to be working, basically everything stays the same except that the date does appear in the availability table.

Comment: Joe, this is why you're a senior database admin and I'm just a lowly entry level report writer :-P

Comment: @Cecil: I added a new query to my answer to explicitly illustrate what I was trying to describe before. See if that gets you what you need.

Comment: @ryebr3ad: We all started somewhere! Keep learning and you'll get there. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Use INNER JOIN, which links tables to each other based on a common attribute (typically a primary - foreign key relationship)

say an attribute, 'id', links table1 and table2

```
SELECT t1.att1, t2.att2
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2  
    ON t1.id = t2.id  --essentially, this links ids that are equal with each other together to make one large table row
```

To add more tables, just add more join clauses.

Comment: +1 Was going to answer with the specific query needed, but I think it's best to just apply advice and arrive at the answer yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that ... Ill have a look into that, JOIN's are a bit scary for a newbie like me though hahah

Comment: I typically think in joins only, since all I do at my job so far is query the database.  You'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe something like this

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM internalrole WHERE introle = $imarole) AND archive = 0 and status = 8;
```

A handy thing for me to remember is that tables are essentially arrays in SQL.

HTH!

Comment: joins are almost always significantly faster than sub-queries

Comment: Hey, thanks for that ... Its a start ... How would i then check the availability table for the other data?

Comment: @Dagon Yep, joins are quicker!
@Cecil Just join to the availability table

Answer (score 0):

Nested queries are your friend.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id in (SELECT user_id FROM internalrole WHERE introle = $imarole) AND archive = 0 and status = 8
```

Alternatively joins:

```
SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN internalrole ON users.id = internalrole.user_id WHERE internalrole.user_id = $imarole AND users.archive = 0 and users.status = 8
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the 3rd table query to the nested query?